# UNWIND statement in Cypher Neo4J does not get executed if the previous one did not have any results?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This request below usually works when I have a match on `c_from` and `c_to`:

```
MATCH (u:User {uid: $userId}) 
WITH u UNWIND $statements as statement  
WITH u, statement 
UNWIND statement.conceptsRelations as conceptsRelation 
MATCH (c_from:Concept{name: conceptsRelation.from}) 
MATCH (c_to:Concept{name: conceptsRelation.to}) 
CREATE (c_from)-[:TO {context:conceptsRelation.context,statement:conceptsRelation.statement,user:u.uid,timestamp:conceptsRelation.timestamp, uid:apoc.create.uuid(), gapscan:conceptsRelation.gapscan, weight: conceptsRelation.weight}]->(c_to)  
WITH u, statement 
UNWIND statement.mentionsRelations as mentionsRelation 
MATCH (m_from:Concept{name: mentionsRelation.from}) 
MATCH (m_to:Concept{name: mentionsRelation.to}) return m_from, m_to
```

However, as soon as I don't have any match the last part of the query (the last `UNWIND`) does not get executed. I checked it by removing the 2nd `UNWIND` and then the 3rd one works again. As in:

```
MATCH (u:User {uid: $userId}) 
WITH u UNWIND $statements as statement  
WITH u, statement 
UNWIND statement.mentionsRelations as mentionsRelation 
MATCH (m_from:Concept{name: mentionsRelation.from}) 
MATCH (m_to:Concept{name: mentionsRelation.to}) return m_from, m_to
```

Just in case, my params are:

`{
  "userId": "15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9",
  "contextNames": [
    {
      "uid": "af8debb0-1f71-11e9-a572-691cc47b060f",
      "name": "dsfasdf"
    }
  ],
  "statements": [
    {
      "text": "@submit desire",
      "concepts": [
        "desire"
      ],
      "mentions": [
        "@submit"
      ],
      "timestamp": 15482915128250000,
      "name": "#desire @@submit ",
      "uid": "2bd1f170-1f73-11e9-a508-0d8a16ad5cf6",
      "uniqueconcepts": [
        "desire"
      ],
      "conceptsRelations": [],
      "mentionsRelations": [
        {
          "from": "desire",
          "to": "@submit",
          "context": "af8debb0-1f71-11e9-a572-691cc47b060f",
          "statement": "2bd1f170-1f73-11e9-a508-0d8a16ad5cf6",
          "user": "15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9",
          "timestamp": 15482915128250000,
          "uid": "apoc.create.uuid()",
          "gapscan": "1",
          "weight": 3
        }
      ],
      "uniquementions": [
        "@submit"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "timestamp": 15482915128250000
}`

This seems like a strange illogical behavior. Any idea why it arises? Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect to happen if there are no statements?

Answer (score 0):

The use of UNWIND is to turn a list into rows
If you have an empty list you get zero rows.

You could add an element to the list if it's empty:

`UNWIND case when size(list) = 0 then [null] else list end`

or

`UNWIND list + null`

And then skip the special value in your 2nd part.